# can not connect a DB instance Running the PostgreSQL Database Engine to pgadmin4

Tags: database, postgresql, centos, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I want to configure Postgres with pgadmin on centos7. but unable to create a server on pgadmin.

I edited file `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` as this :

```
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

and edited file /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf as this :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

the I restarted PostgreSQL with this command: `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

and here is my configuration in pgadmin4:
[image: pgadmin4 configuration]

but after I click on the save button nothing happens

so my question is how to configure Postgres with pgadmin on centos7, and what I've done wrong in this process?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to Postgres on psql to ensure that everything is ok?

Comment: @kanataki yes I've done that . it was ok ...

Comment: Try with 127.0.0.1, I have tried duplicating the error but can't. However, my centos can't translate 127.0.0/.1 to any hostname. the IP 127.0.0.1 is working well though